# Callback code seems to run before callback is actually called

Tags: javascript

This sounds like a weird title and probably not stated too well.  But here's the issue.

I've got this method being called:

```
function BindFacebookAlbumAndPhotoData() 
{
    GetAllFacebookAlbums(userID, accessToken, function(aAlbums) 
    {
        if (aAlbums === null || aAlbums === undefined) 
        {
            // TODO: Need to handle this
            return;
        }

        var defaultAlbumID = aAlbums[0].id;

        BindFacebookAlbumDropdownList(aAlbums, defaultAlbumID);

        BindFacebookThumbnails(userID, accessToken, defaultAlbumID, photosContainerDivID);

        SetSelectDefaultOption(defaultAlbumID);
    });
}
```

So here's the GetAllFacebookAlbums Method:

```
function GetAllFacebookAlbums(userID, accessToken, callbackFunction)
{
    var aAlbums = [];
    var uri = "/" + userID + "/albums?access_token=" + accessToken;

    // this is an async call so code after this will fire at the same time
    FB.api(uri, function(response) 
    {
        // check for a valid response
        if (!response || response.error) 
        {
            callbackFunction(albums);
        }

        for (var i = 0, l = response.data.length; i < l; i++) 
        {
            //do whatever
        }
    });

    // wait for the FB.api call to run a bit before calling code below
    window.setTimeout(callbackFunction(aAlbums), 5000);
}
```

What's happening is this line is being called before the setTimeout it seems:

```
var defaultAlbumID = aAlbums[0].id;
```

the whole reason I put that timeout in there is so I can wait for the FB.api call to finish.  Then call the callback after I know I have data.  So how in the world are those lines in my callback being called when I have definitely not seen a 5 second delay before that callback is called?

Comment: Have you tried using quotes around the js argument of your settimeout? I've only ever seen it passed as a string. Sort of like: setTimeout("alert('hello')", 5000);

Comment: @Jage That's actually not the best way to do things. Much better and more flexible to pass a reference to a function.

Comment: I don't get why a var reference would be more efficient and yes, should have been quotes, good catch.

Comment: No, @CoffeeAddict, honestly you should read up on the way people really write Javascript code nowadays (like for the last 5 years or so). Not trying to be harsh - there are approx. one zillion really good Javascript tutorials and many, many blogs out there. The first time I read some of Douglas Crockford's stuff I felt like a really bright light had been turned on in a dark room :-)

Comment: Also, good luck, and I'm glad you're making progress!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line right here:

```
window.setTimeout(callbackFunction(aAlbums), 5000);
```

You're calling the function right there in the `setTimeout()` call. Wrap it in another function:

```
window.setTimeout(function() { callbackFunction(aAlbums); }, 5000);
```

Now, that said, the whole setup doesn't really make much sense. You've already got code sitting in a place that you know will be called *as soon as the data is ready*.  That's the code in the Facebook API callback you've got. Why not just call your "callbackFunction" from in there?

Comment: "You've already got code sitting in a place that you know will be called as soon as the data is ready".  Not necessarily.  The FB.api call is an async call so my callback (callbackFunction(aAlbums)) is being called at the same time my FB.api call is being called.

Comment: "That's the code in the Facebook API callback you've got. Why not just call your "callbackFunction" from in there?".  I've tried that already in the past, and got all sorts of hell.  Because if you do that, then what happens is the callback for FB.api never gets hit/run if that last callback to callbackFunction(aAlbums) is called from within the FB.api callback itself

Comment: ??? huh?  No, I don't think that's correct. The whole point of "complete" APIs like that is to give you a way to run code at the completion of some asynchronous process.  Nobody uses timeouts to deal with that, because it's completely unreliable and it wastes the user's time (potentially).

Comment: weird, now it works...as in before if I were to call the callback from within my FB.api it was just causing me problems.

Comment: Yes I know that's the whole point...but at the time I was trying that it was causing issues by doing it that way.  Trust me.  I was not getting the response back, but it was most likely a different problem then it looks like.  So I put it back in there as you suggested and yes, that was my original intent in the first place, but I got away from it because it was causing me issues in the past for whatever reason related or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding you should do

```
    [/code` window.setTimeout(callbackFunction, 5000, aAlbums);`]
```

instead of:

```
    [/code`window.setTimeout(function() { callbackFunction(aAlbums); }, 5000);`]
```

I do belive both will work, but the first seems easier to read, write and understand